# requests_html html.arender seems can't work

Tags: python, python-requests-html

Using requests_html  below code , I can get the links of AMAZON BEST SELLERS. But I only can get 31 items links ,the correct should be 50 linkages . How to fix it ? Thanks! ( I added `h.html.arender(scrolldown = 10,sleep = 2)` , it's seems not work )

```
import pyppeteer
import pandas as pd
import os
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/gp/bestsellers/industrial/2680372051/ref=zg_bs_pg_1_industrial?ie=UTF8&pg=1"
h = session.get(url=url)
h.html.arender(scrolldown = 10,sleep = 2)

links_my = h.html.absolute_links

links_my_df = pd.DataFrame(links_my,columns=['link'])
result = links_my_df.loc[links_my_df['link'].str.contains("dp")]

result.describe()
```